# phonegap app loads first page upon screen orientation change

Tags: android, cordova

i am developing an android app using phonegap. i have multiple pages in the app and a single activity. whenever i change the orientation of the device, no matter which page i am on, the app loads the first page which is shown when the app is launched. i assumed it was because i had not overriden the onResume() method in the activity, but even that failed to solve the problem.

EDIT: This issue does not arise if the app is paused and the resumed.

My activity:

```
public class MainScreen extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/landing.html");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added Manifest file
My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.code"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.miniorange.authenticator.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.miniorange.authenticator.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.miniorange.authenticator.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.miniorange.authenticator.MainScreen">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity"/>
            <receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="com.me.code" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

what may be the solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you please post your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

sorry ... ( answering it late :D )

I had this problem with my app :

When I change the orientation, activity reloads ...

And I found this solution :

add this attribute to your `<activity>` tags :

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

suggestion ... use this insted (better) :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
```

==========================================

information about solution :

what is the reason .. (?)

It'll say to application that you want to handle this changes (orientation, keyboardHidden, keyboard, screenSize, locale, etc.) yourself.